# Laravel set default language not working

Tags: php, laravel, localization

I have changed the default website localization in confing/app.php to be (de)

```
'locale' => 'de',
'fallback_locale' => 'de',
```

But still website is loading in 'en' localization .

I tried clearing the view cache and cache but nothing changed .

I am using 
https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization

The de will be activate only when i use the URL
domainname.com/de

Comment: did you clear the 'config' cache? did you set 'useAcceptLanguageHeader' correctly?

Comment: @lagbox yes i cleared the config cache nothing changed. I don't have accept language header right now. But i want to force using de language

Comment: so you didn't touch the config file for this package?

Comment: @lagbox I just uncommitted the required language in config/laravellocalization.php

Comment: and how about the other vars in that config file

Comment: @lagbox nothing changed just uncommitted the 'de' line

Comment: so how about the other vars with the comments that tell you what they are for ... any of them sound like they are important?

Comment: @lagbox yes i think there was one that sound like it's important :) 'useAcceptLanguageHeader' => true, Changed to false , issue solved

Comment: ;) ... ill post that up

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the scenario to not be using the dynamic locale in the URL it seems you will have to adjust the configuration file for this package:

```
'useAcceptLanguageHeader' => false,
```

From the comments for that variable:

> "Negotiate for the user locale using the Accept-Language header if it's not defined in the URL? If false, system will take app.php locale attribute"

Seems to get it to use that default you have to set this to false.

You could play with the other variable:

```
'hideDefaultLocaleInURL' => true,
```

to see how that adjusts the default behavior as well.

Comment: you saved my day!

Comment: how to search file?

Answer (score 4):

i had the same proplem
go to laravellocalization.php in config

and make

'useAcceptLanguageHeader' => false,

and then run

php artisan config:clear

and it will work

Answer (score 1):

this way is best for me

`app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`

in boot() function write these lines

`session()->put('locale', 'ar');`

`app()->setLocale(session()->get('locale'));`

Answer (score 0):

try to add __construct() function to your controller. :)

```
public function __construct(){}
```

Answer (score 0):

//To make the default website with the language AR.

//At the first time, the user does not have any session. So, we will add a

//session and set the language to be AR if it is not the first time.

//Then, depending on the language you choose.

//In the web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    if (Session::get('language') == 'en') {
        Session::put('language', 'en');
        App::setLocale('en');
        return redirect('main-services/1/1');
    } else {
        Session::put('language', 'ar');
        App::setLocale('ar');
        return redirect('main-services/1/1');
    }
});
```